# time difference in JS has wrong result

Tags: javascript

I have two text-input-fields where users can enter a time in format "hh:mm". The main part looks like the following code:

```
    var time1 = new Date("01/01/2013 " + time1input);   
    var time2 = new Date("01/01/2013 " + time2input);
    var difference = new Date(time2 - time1);
```

The result is always 01:00 to high (e.g. 08:00 - 04:00 results in 05:00 which is obviously wrong :) ). Did i misunderstood something?

Comment: What makes you think that subtracting dates works as you expect in JavaScript?

Comment: maybe because i am a naive javascript beginner

Answer (score 5):

You can't work with dates like that.

Try the following instead:

```
var time1input = "04:00";
var time2input = "08:00";

var time1 = new Date("01/01/2013 " + time1input);   
var time2 = new Date("01/01/2013 " + time2input);
var difference = time2.getTime() - time1.getTime();
console.log(difference / 60 / 60 / 1000); //<- whittle this down to hours
```

That will log out '4'.

If you're working with times, use something like http://momentjs.com/, which lets you do cool stuff like..

```
difference = moment(time2).diff(time1, 'hours'); //<- will return 4
```

Format (hh:mm): (assuming use of difference from first example)

```
var hours = Math.floor(difference / 60 / 60 / 1000);
var minutes = Math.round(difference / 60 / 1000) % 60;
var formattedString = (hours > 10 ? hours : "0" + hours) + ":" + (minutes > 10 ? minutes : "0" + minutes);
```

A 4 hour difference will return "04:00", a 13 hour, 30 minute difference will return 13:30.

Comment: I was writing about Moment.js :(

Comment: Aw, sorry man. Super useful library, always my 'goto' whenever anyone says "Date".

Comment: wow cool. but what if i want the difference to be in the format hh:mm?

Comment: Updated. There are a hundred different ways of doing it really.. and the example I gave doesn't take into account multi-day differences (i.e. 2 days will give 48 hours). You'll kind of have to hack away at that.

Comment: var time1 = new Date("01/01/2013 " + departureTimeInput);

says invalid date. although 

departureTimeInput is "04:00"

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `getTime` method.  This might work:

```
var difference = new Date(time2.getTime() - time1.getTime());
```

Comment: I don't think it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/mageek/RAfrU/1/

Comment: This is exactly what OP's code does.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when we calculate time differences.

> we used to convert it to milliseconds, find difference and convert
>   back to a format.

check this [post](http://forums.aspfree.com/html-javascript-css-help-7/calculate-difference-between-two-times-212351.html)

Answer (score 0):

also:

```
var time1 = new Date("01/01/2013 " + time1input)
var time2 = new Date("01/01/2013 " + time2input)
var difference = time2 - time1
```

`difference` is a difference in milliseconds, so to get a difference in hours you can do:

```
var time1 = new Date("01/01/2013 04:00")
var time2 = new Date("01/01/2013 08:00")
var difference = (time2 - time1)/1000/60/60
console.log(difference)
# => 4
```

Notice that you can operate with Date objects directly, it's not necessary to call `.getTime()`

p.s. a similar question has already been answered a [long long time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)